# vsftp virtual users setup configuration

Tags: linux, ftp, installation, centos5

I can't get vsftp virtual user to work… I'm trying to setup a virtual user for web developers that are restricted to only the apache document root folder.

CentOS 5.9(Final), vsftpd 2.0.5, pam 0.99.6.2

setup pam service file (/etc/pam.d/vsftp_vusers) as:

```
auth required pam_pwdfile.so pwdfile /etc/vsftpd/passwd
account required pam_permit.so
```

setup htpasswd by:

```
$htpasswd /etc/vsftpd/passwd user_a
$chmod 600 /etc/vsftpd/passwd
```

also tried:

```
$htpasswd -m /etc/vsftpd/passwd user_a
```

build user_list file (/etc/vsftpd/user_list) as:

```
user_a
```

build account document and authority file  (/etc/vsftpd/user/user_a) as:

```
local_root=/var/www/
```

configured vsftpd (/etc/vsftpd.conf) as:

```
pasv_min_port=65500
pasv_max_port=65535
listen_port=21
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
userlist_deny=NO
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd/user_list
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/user_list
xferlog_enable=YES
dual_log_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_std_format=YES
listen=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES

## VUSER ##
pam_service_name=vsftpd_vusers
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd/user
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
guest_enable=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd
hide_ids=YES
```

When I tried to login locally, 530 login incorrect were given. I tried countless times to make sure I got the right username and password…

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No. It took too much time. We tried other software.

Answer (score -1):

This solved 530 error:

```
pam_service_name=ftp
```

Comment: The pam service-file for T1000 seems to be `/etc/pam.d/vsftp_vusers` so it should be `pam_service_name=vsftp_vusers`, right?